# In node compositing, how do I delay a movie clip by any given number of seconds

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes

I am creating motion graphics first in black and white, before colorizing them.  I am doing that with only kinetic text and transitions. I am overlaying one video clip upon another, but I wish to delay an underlying video clip by 30 seconds or 30 frames (30fps). How do I do that in node compositing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Movie Clip Editor` open `N-Panel`, go to the bottom and find `Footage Settings`. Here you can control Start/Offset frame, these values can be animated.

Comment: You are a wonder and thank you very much.